# ReSharper help: Possible NullReferenceException

Tags: resharper, nullreferenceexception

ReSharper says "Check if 'UserHostAddress' is not null" when I'm accessing `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress` (it is in a try/catch block).

Within another method get the following property from the request object:

`HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl`

How does ReSharper determine or "know" that Request cannot be `null`? Or `Current`? Or `HttpContext`?

Maybe it is a bad example with this framework object chain but I think you get the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R# uses its included [External Annotations](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__External_Annotations.html) to provide these code annotations for types within the .NET Framework (like your mentioned ASP.NET classes).

The reason, why Jetbrains annotated for example `HttpContext.Current` as nullable is that in an console application (an application without HTTP context) `HttpContext.Current` returns `null`.

Comment: But I can trust R# there? Do I really only have to check HttpContext.Current and not HttpContext before and HttpContext.Current.Request afterwards? I mean if I really have such an object chain in front of me.